# pipwerks JS SCORM API wrapper sets completed module to incomplete on re-entry

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm2004

**Main thrust of question:**

When a user re-enters a module which they had already completed and passed, the LMS reflects the course as not having been passed by unchecking the second checkbox in the course menu. It seems that the [pipwerks SCORM API wrapper for JS](http://pipwerks.com/laboratory/scorm/api-wrapper-javascript/) cannot get a satisfactory status of the course from the LMS and it is automatically setting back the status to `incomplete`. How can I fix this?

**Background and Environment**

We've created an HTML/CSS/JS course which is packaged as a multi-SCO PIF. Each SCO within contains a series of slides and an assessment. When a user has gone through all the slides and taken the assessment, I set `cmi.completion_status` to `completed`. If they passed the assessment, I set `cmi.success_status` to `passed` and if not I set it to `failed`.

The below code snippet shows use of my custom SCORM session and assessment scoring code to do this:

```
if (scorm_session && scoring_info.isComplete()) {
    scorm_session.setParam('cmi.score.min', 0);
    scorm_session.setParam('cmi.score.max', 100);
    scorm_session.setParam('cmi.score.raw', scoring_info.getScore());
    scorm_session.setParam('cmi.success_status', scoring_info.isPass() ? 'passed' : 'failed');
    scorm_session.setParam('cmi.completion_status', 'completed');
}
```

**This works correctly**--I see the AJAX request go out with the proper statuses in the data. Further, I see in the LMS course menu that the first checkbox for that module gets checked for completion, and if passed I see the second one get checked as well.

When the user leaves that module to go to another, those checkboxes stay checked correctly. If the user completely exits the course and later comes back, those boxes are still checked. **If, however, the user re-enters a module he has passed by clicking the title in the course menu, the "passed" checkbox gets unchecked.** So if user wants to go back and look at something in a module he has already completed and passed, he is given the visual indication that he is no longer considered to have passed the course.

It appears that this status change is being triggered by the [pipwerks SCORM API wrapper for JS](http://pipwerks.com/laboratory/scorm/api-wrapper-javascript/), but it's due to info it gets back from the LMS on module entry. I see in the console that, on entry, the API asks the LMS for the course status (the API wrapper runs `scorm.status("get");`). If it receives `not attempted` or `unknown` it calls `scorm.status("set", "incomplete")`.

I see in the console that the request for status goes out and `unknown` is returned--even when I have explicitly set it to `completed` and `passed`. I then immediately see a transmission setting the status to `incomplete` as the code I described says it will.

This is happening both on http://cloud.scorm.com as well as a Moodle installation we have in place.

Comment: What is cmi.exit set to? And what does the LMS return for cmi.entry? As far as I recall (without checking the code), if you set success_status = passed and completion_status = completed in the pipwerks wrapper, by default it will send cmi.exit = "normal" automatically - that tells the LMS that the attempt on that SCO has ended, and it will look at the next session as a new attempt - giving you a new data model (cmi.entry will be "ab-initio").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By spec, if a SCORM SCO is completed, then subsequently relaunched, the second launch is to be treated as a new attempt. This cannot be controlled by the course, this can only be overridden in the LMS's course handling and/or launch options. Not all LMSs provide this option, but I've seen it in Moodle (SCORM 1.2), and I imagine SCORM Cloud would provide the option, too.

Regarding the wrapper's handling of the completion status, the wrapper sets `incomplete` only if the course status is `not attempted` or `unknown`. If the LMS returns any other value, the wrapper will leave it alone.

If you feel the wrapper's completion status handling is causing a problem, you can disable it by setting this flag before initializing the course:

```
scorm.handleCompletionStatus = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected you'd see this question. :) I do not believe the API Wrapper is in error here, and I apologize that the framing of the question made it appear so. When you say, "this can only be overridden in the LMS's course handling and/or launch options," do you mean there may be something I can set in the manifest as an option? Or are you saying this is purely LMS-implementation specific and there is nothing I, a course author/packager, can do about it?

Comment: Yes, I lurk in these parts. :) RE: your question, the latter. The package author has no control, it depends completely on the LMS's SCORM implementation and the options selected by the person importing the course into the LMS. It usually shows up as an option when importing the package, something along the lines of "select relaunch behavior: 'new attempt' or 'review mode'". Had a quick look at SCORM Clooud, I don't see this option there (which makes sense since it's not part of the spec).